# Error using one package from another "class interface or enum expected"

Tags: java

```
package students;
import java.util.*;

public class p1 {
    private int n1 = 2;
    int n2 = 3;
    protected int n3 = 5;
    public int n4 = 7;
}

package students1;

class abc extends students.p1 {
    public static void main( String args[]) {
        abc obj = new abc();
        System.out.println(obj.n4);
        System.out.println(obj.n3);
    }
}
```

This is my code but its giving an error class interface or enum expected at the package statements

Comment: typo on first line. Are these separated into two files?

Comment: packagae  should be package in first line.

Comment: @AlexGittemeier these are in the same file .. i corrected the typo as well but still giving the error  class , interface or enum expected at line 10 i.e. package students 1

Answer (score 3):

These **must** be in separate files. One named p1.java, the other named abc.java, and `abc` should be a public class.

As a side note, it is good practice to start your type names with a capital letter, so you should have two classes: `P1.java` and `Abc.java`, instead of `p1.java` and `abc.java`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 `package` per file, and it must match the folder name the file is in and be on the first line.
So you have to split this into two files, one named `p1.java` in folder `students` and the other named `abc.java` in folder `students1`.
The class then has the same name as the file (without .java) and has to be `public`.

Also note that you have to change the variable names in class p1, they cannot start with a number.

It is also good practice to start class names with uppercase letters, like `Abc`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
packagae students;
```

Should be:

```
package students;
```

Note that the first example includes a typo (more precisely the `a` between `g` and `e`).